# Understanding use of const buffer and read() in C

Tags: c, buffer, constants

I was under the impression that a const value in C could not be changed. However, I wrote this contrived example that, to me at least, appears to change the value of a constant. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void test(const char* buffer, int num);

int main(){
    const char buffer[10];
    test(buffer, 1);
    printf("main 1: %s\n", buffer);
    test(buffer, 2);
    printf("main 2: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}

void test(const char* buffer, int num) {
    read(0, (void *)buffer, 10);
    printf("test %da: %s", num, buffer);
    buffer = "num";
    printf("test %db: %s\n", num, buffer);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
me@computer:~/C$ ./a.out 
123
test 1a: 123
test 1b: num
main 1: 123

456
test 2a: 456
test 2b: num
main 2: 456
```

1. The `const buffer` in main has its value changed after each call to `test()`. Why?
2. In `test()`, I am able to change the value of `buffer` to `"num"` in the method scope, which I thought shouldn't be possible...?
3. When I change the value of buffer to `"num"` while in `test()`, that change isn't reflected in `main()`, which makes sense because of pass-by-value. However, `buffer` in `main()` does indeed change. Instead of being `"num"`, the value that was inputted into the call to `read()` is stored in `buffer`. First off, why isn't the value `"num"` since that line of code is after `read()`? Second, why is `buffer` in `main()` changed at all?

***EDIT***:
A thought just occurred to me: if the typecast can do away with the `const` modifier, then what's the point of using `const` for parameters? I thought it was for assurance that the values passed into function would not be altered. This workaround seems to defeat the whole purpose of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because you've used a typecast to remove the `const`.
2. You are changing the value of the pointer to the address of `"num"`. You didn't make the pointer `const`, just what it points to. So you're allowed to change the pointer itself to point elsewhere. To make the pointer itself `const` as well, try `const char * const buffer`
3. See 2. You just changed where your local parameter `buffer` points. That does not change where main's local variable `buffer` points.

Comment: The typecast! I didn't realize it removed the `const` modifier. Good to know! Also the second question seems stupidly obvious now...If I had `*buffer = "num";` that would be illegal. Good answer; very fast too!

Comment: Can you comment on the edit? I removed the check mark temporarily to get you to answer the edit. I'll add it back.

Comment: It's part of C's general philosophy to trust the programmer. It also shows how typecasts are dangerous and should be avoided. But sometimes it may be useful (or expedient) to do such a thing. Think about it this way: if you didn't put in the const in the first place then you'd be able to modify it. So it's always up to you. Good point though. It shows that there are no guarantees. Still, it would generally be considered bad practice since you're telling the caller you won't modify it, but in fact you do.